# How to use %debug_package while using rpmbuild?

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

Linux version 2.6.18-131.el5
gcc version 4.1.2 
RPM version 4.4.2.3

I use the following command to build packages:
$ sudo rpmbuild -ba xxx.spec

I thought that the debuginfo package should be built by default, but only get the xxx.src.rpm and xxx.x86_64.rpm, with no debuginfo package.

Then I add a line in my xxx.spec, "#%debug_package":

[image]

Then the debug package is built!
But I thought that a line with a '#' in the front is considered as comment!
How does this work?

I'm totally confused.

Comment: I've solved the problem.I install the package redhat-rpm-config and then get the debuginfo package by default. 
But can anyone tell me how does the package effect the building of debuginfo?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is one of the most annoying "features" in `rpm` and it gets people *all the time*. The `#` is only commenting out the first line of a multi-line macro. The proper way to comment it out would be

```
#%%debug_package
```

The first `%` escapes the second; the result after macro becomes what you wanted.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.But why the debug_package is not built by default?

Comment: You should be able to completely remove that line, as debuginfo packages should be built automatically (if not, you probably need to install redhat-rpm-config). I've put some brief info about it at http://distracted-it.blogspot.com/2014/08/building-rpm-debuginfo-package-not.html

Comment: this also suggests same with more explanation: https://trac.netlabs.org/rpm/wiki/RpmHowToPackagers#Generatingdebuginfopackages